# Images not showing up in html?

Tags: html, css, github

I have just published a free site on github, however the images are not showing up there is a blank box where theyre supposed to be. the website link is: https://joshua-mcfield99.github.io/joshuamcfield.github.io/about.html . it works on vs live serever but for some reason not on git. please help this noob mistake im doi.

I have coded the correct file path,

```
    <img src="/images/me.png">
```

the file where the img is stored is named images
[this is the files in the repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCuAz.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and don't work around errors presented to you by just adding numbers to the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly remove `/` from it. The correct way is:
<`img src="images/me.png">`

The image you have mentioned is absolute URL, which is `/` which means your page is expecting the image from the root directory.

Once you remove the `/` it means your are reading the image from your webpage current location which is relative.

Comment: thankyou for explaining the whole situation i have struggled with other posts because of learning difficulties and you have explained the matter very well thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the '/' from the beginning of the image URL and it will work